# How to prevent zoom-creep?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, troubleshooting, zoom-lock, zoom-creep

The Nikkor 18-200mm VR lens creeps until fully extended if pointed vertically down.

This is preventing me from using it on a [rostrum camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rostrum_camera).

Is there a piece of equipment or a simple (and non-destructive!) hack to hold the zoom in place?

I found [a blog post that suggests using a rubber band](http://digitalphotographyblogs.com/2008/07/22/lens-creep-what-it-is-and-one-way-to-stop-it/) half-overlapping the zoom ring, but that doesn't sound very secure. I'm really after something that will hold it exactly where I put it for a really long time.

Comment: You could use sticky tack or masking tape. Both of these will come off easy with little or no residue and should be sturdy enough to hold it.

Comment: Some masking tapes will leave a mess behind, either because the adhesive will remain, or the tape will tear. It can be icky. That's the technical term for it. "Icky" :-)

Comment: the blog link is pointing to a spam website

Comment: Do you have to zoom in this set up? Would it be silly to suggest a prime lens?

Answer (score 9):

Well, other than a strong rubber band, the other alternative I can think of is [Gaffer tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaffer_tape) which, unlike duct tape, doesn't leave a residue. However, I think a rubber band will work if the band is good quality and thick and so I would go the rubber band route first, to find out, and failing that go with gaffer tape.

Comment: +1. If one rubber band isn't enough, you could try 2.

Comment: Gaffer's tape is used all the time to hold the lens setting for remote cameras when hanging in arenas. Works nicely.

Comment: @Greg - Yep, it's a very handy thing to have. The downside is re-use, of course, which is why I suggested he try the rubber band first.

Comment: I'd never consider reusing the tape. It's so cheap there's no point. Just wrap it around the barrel once or twice, then tear it off later and toss it. Tape is very useful for other things encountered while shooting too, from helping to hold things out of the way to hold clothes in place.

Comment: BTW, look here for some more talk an Gaffer's tape: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7753/how-to-choose-a-gaffers-tape.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a rubber band plus one or more toothpicks or paperclips to catch the knurls on the zoom ring more exactly. Or if the rubber band isn't holding reliably enough, you could try a bit of hot glue to fix the toothpicks in place - hot glue generally scrapes off pretty well.

Alternatively, depending on your budget, you could buy a manual focus prime lens of the proper focal length, which would be inexpensive. Since it's a static setup, the effort of setting the focus would be well amortized. (Of course, you might still need a rubber band to keep the focus from being bumped!)

Answer (score 0):

A company called [Lensband](http://lensband.com) has a solution for zoom creep, a silicone band that fits the barrel of the zoom lens.

Comment: Hi! Are you associated with this company, by any chance? Please read the FAQ on self-promotion if so. And even if not, we'd really like longer, authoritative answers — have you used this product, and how did it work? How does it compare to alternatives?

Comment: @mattdm The answer appears complete. Simple question, simple answer. Verbiage is not an indicator of quality. However, he is 4.5 years late.

Comment: @paul I dunno. Does it work, or is it a gimmick? Does it work in all situations, with all lenses? On the other hand, for something like this, time isn't really important — zoom lens design hasn't changed that much in 4 years.

Comment: That looks very similar to a charity wristband. So one of those could work, if its the right diameter for your lens.