# How to choose a gaffer's tape?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, accessories, low-budget

After a long time using my flash with rubber bands to hold flash accessories, I decided to try the Gaffer's tape method recommended by many photogs. So, I searched for that on B&H's website and got [multiple results](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ns=p_PRICE_2|0&Ntt=gaffer+tape&N=0). Some of the results explicitly mention [no residue](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/724340-REG/Rosco_851422232425_Gaffer_Tape_1_x.html) and [some don't](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/20008-REG/General_Brand_Gaffer_Cloth_Tape.html).

In the past I bought a "painter's tape" at Home Depot that supposedly leaves no residue as well, but this feature is limited to 14-days of contact.

So, any *particular* suggestion for a *cheap* non-residue gaffer's tape? Something that will tear off a year from now without leftover? I just need ~30cm, so spending $8-$10 on a full roll already seems excessive, so I'm more inclined to the cheap side...

Comment: Nobody needs only ~30cm of gaffa. You know the old joke - if it moves and shouldn't, use the tape; if it doesn't and should, use the WD-40...

Comment: @Staale S - LOL! Seriously now, if Gaffer's can keep its adhesion for extended period of times, then I need about that long to wrap around the flash head so I can safely stick stuff *to* that tape surface without leaving traces once removed.

Comment: Well, seriously... for my flash I use the wide rubber band with Velcro on it approach to hold stuff in place. Something like this... (argh, hopeless URL; just google for the term "flash velcro rubber band" without quotes, the first one is a reference to a page with a Gary Fong whaletail setup which is the page I mean) It works well enough for me, though I haven't used it for anything heavy. Some quick googling did not look promising for you; "Despite the claims they make about gaffer tape it will not stick very well in the cold and if you leave it on too long it will leave residue behind".

Comment: @Staale S - I do not stick very well in the cold either... but seeing where you are from, I'm sure you last far longer than any tape... ;-)

Comment: @Staale S - BTW, if you make this an answer, I can rep you.

Comment: If it's for (semi)permanent use, then don't worry about the kind of tape -- either lighter fluid or isopropyl alcohol will remove any residue (depending on the adhesive). (And yes, there are "goo removers" you can get if you really want to pay more than necessary.) Residue-free tape (and, frankly, gaffer's tape in general) is more about setting up for a shot in studio or on location than it is about Frankensteining equipment -- you want to be able to tear down cleanly when you're done.

Comment: @Stan Rogers - thanks, won't the alcohol leave marks on the black finish of the flash? I think I prefer some residue over ugly rubbing marks...

Comment: I used (denatured) alcohol to get rid of some nasty-decade-old tape gunk from a well-loved EOS 1N I got a couple of years ago. Worked like a charm, it is now clean as a baby's bottom.

Comment: Nope, not unless there's something seriously wrong with the plastic, or you're using a cloth that's sold in the abrasives department of the hardware store. Like anything else in life, let the tool do the work -- let the solvent dissolve the glue, and just wipe off the solution. A couple of goes and you'd never know there was ever anything there.

Comment: It was electrian's tape by the way. The kind that leaves a really sticky mess behind when you rip it off.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's helpful. However, there one method I have yet to try - a band from a mountain bike's tube. Hopefully it can stretch long enough to get on a 580EXII...

Comment: Not a budget solution, but [magmods](https://magnetmod.com/) seems a cleaner way to do the accessories thing on speedlights than either tape or velcro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my flash I use the wide rubber band with Velcro on it approach to hold stuff in place. Something like [this](http://photo-tips-online.com/review/gary-fong-whaletail-flash-diffuser/gallery.php?id=gary-fong-whaletail-flash-diffuser-8) (the same one as used in Gary Fong's WhaleTail flash diffuser).
It works well enough for me, though I haven't used it for anything heavy. Some quick googling did not look promising for you; "Despite the claims they make about gaffer tape it will not stick very well in the cold and if you leave it on too long it will leave residue behind".